# Data structure for like/favorite in social blogging app

Tags: json, database, postgresql

What's the best way to save data in db to keep track of a user clicked a like/favorite button or not?

I've tried the following data structure:

`postId:{
  ...
  like_count:123,
  user_who_liked:[uid1,uid2,uid3...]
}`

When the data above is downloaded to the client, we can check if the client liked the post or not by checking if the array `user_who_liked` contains the client's uid or not. However, if there are more than 1000 items in the `user_who_liked` array, this approach consumes too much redundant bandwidth.

I found the following json data from instagram:

`{
  ...
  viewer_has_liked: false
  viewer_has_saved: false
  viewer_has_saved_to_collection: false
  viewer_in_photo_of_you: false
}`

This approach seems more efficient, but how do the database know if the user has liked or not? Do they store a bunch of uids and check if the user's uid is inside it? Are those has_liked/has_saved booleans derived attributes?

Comment: Why don't you properly normalize this?

Comment: Do you mean separate `user_who_liked` from the post?

Comment: can you edit your post and write your DB schemas?